# Disable App Windows On Chrome

Tags: google-chrome

[image]I'm looking for a way to disable the stupid miniwindows that some sites use on chrome. I would like for chrome to open up a normal tab when a link that asks for one of those little windows is requested to be opened. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: A screenshot would be helpful to identify what you mean by "stupid miniwindows" unique to Chrome.

Comment: Having used moodle myself in the past, I can tell you that this behavior, would extend to any browser not just Chrome

Comment: Plugins can do what you want. But the plugins I've worked with that do this are only for Firefox as Chrome's plugin model does not allow that level of interaction with the browser UI.